# Trying to use inplace for a list Pandas

Tags: pandas

i have a list of doritos.

```
doritos=["Spicy Sweet Chili", "Cool Ranch", "Nacho Cheese", "Salsa Verde"]
pd.Series(doritos)
```

Then I sort the values in descending order and that works, but when I try to enter the inplace = True it doesn't look like it keeps in new order.

```
pd.Series(doritos).sort_values(ascending = False)
```

then try this:

```
pd.Series(doritos).sort_values(ascending = False, inplace = True).
```

it reverts back to the original list.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
doritos =["Spicy Sweet Chili", "Cool Ranch", "Nacho Cheese", "Salsa Verde"]
doritos=pd.Series(doritos)
doritos.sort_values(ascending = False,inplace=True)
print(doritos)
```

output

```
0    Spicy Sweet Chili
3          Salsa Verde
2         Nacho Cheese
1           Cool Ranch
dtype: object
```